# web api routing not working for two Get method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

in my web api i tried to get 2 Get methods .one is with parameter and one is without parameter.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {}  
 public HttpResponseMessage GetAll(int id)
    {}
```

my routing like this

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
```

first get method is return value.but second get method with parameter is giving error.pls give some suggession.advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is for MVC. The Visual Studio project template for Web API creates some thing like this in WebApiConfig.cs under App_Start:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

With that, a GET request on `http://localhost:<port>/api/yourcontroller` should call `Get()` and GET on `http://localhost:<port>/api/yourcontroller/123` should call `GetAll(int)`. See [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) for more info.

Comment: but i want to use more than one post in my controller like 2 post or get .so in that time i want to add action key word like "  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" right.if i am not using action keyword its coming but if i add that action keyword ts not coming..

Comment: You can either use the REST style mapping of HTTP verb to action methods, like what I have shown, which is the default. Or, you can use the MVC like RPC-style mappings. You can have routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id} but in that case you have to specify the action in the URI like `http://localhost:<port>/api/yourcontroller/get` or `http://localhost:<port>/api/yourcontroller/getall`.

Comment: yes i did already.i am calling this webapi with method name(action name) only.but its calling all the get method without parameter. with parameter its not calling.its giving error like that method name is not there or removed.

Comment: Are you using the correct URI, for example, `http://localhost:<port>/api/yourcontroller/get` and `http://localhost:<port>/api/yourcontroller/getall/123`? First one should result in Get() getting called and the second one should result in GetAll(int id) getting called with 123 in the URI getting bound to id.